# MySQL Add Where Clause in Correct Place

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

My query:

```
SELECT E.ID
     , E.Name
     , E.StartDate
     , E.Repeats
     , A.ShowDate
     , DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) AS NewShowDate
     , (T.Day-1) AS NewDay
FROM Planner_Lessons E JOIN
 Planner_LessonTimesNew T
 ON T.LessonID = E.ID INNER JOIN Planner_Sessions S ON S.UserID=T.UserID JOIN
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ID DAY) as ShowDate
  FROM `Planner_Tally`
  ORDER BY ID ASC
 ) A 
 ON MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0 AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate AND E.Deleted='No' AND T.Deleted='No' WHERE S.SID='1234' AND NewShowDate<='2014-05-13 00:00:00' ORDER BY NewShowDate ASC
```

But the where clause `NewShowDate<='2014-05-13 00:00:00'` is causing an issue as MySQL says that `NewShowData` cannot be found. As well as an answer I would like an explanation of what is going wrong and how I can solve it. I am a novice with MySQL and wish to learn it in greater detail to help me solve future problems myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use derived subquery

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT E.ID
         , E.Name
         , E.StartDate
         , E.Repeats
         , A.ShowDate
         , DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) AS NewShowDate
         , (T.Day-1) AS NewDay
    FROM Planner_Lessons E JOIN
     Planner_LessonTimesNew T
     ON T.LessonID = E.ID INNER JOIN Planner_Sessions S ON S.UserID=T.UserID JOIN
     (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ID DAY) as ShowDate
      FROM `Planner_Tally`
      ORDER BY ID ASC
     ) A 
     ON MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0 AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate AND E.Deleted='No' AND T.Deleted='No' 
)As Z
WHERE Z.SID='1234' AND Z.NewShowDate<='2014-05-13 00:00:00' ORDER BY Z.NewShowDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of final result set (thus the aliases also) generated after executing `WHERE` clause you can either wrap your query in subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT E.ID
     , E.Name
     , E.StartDate
     , E.Repeats
     , A.ShowDate
     , DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) AS NewShowDate
     , (T.Day-1) AS NewDay
FROM Planner_Lessons E JOIN
 Planner_LessonTimesNew T
 ON T.LessonID = E.ID INNER JOIN Planner_Sessions S ON S.UserID=T.UserID JOIN
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ID DAY) as ShowDate
  FROM `Planner_Tally`
  ORDER BY ID ASC
 ) A 
 ON MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0 AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate AND E.Deleted='No' AND T.Deleted='No'
WHERE S.SID='1234'
) A
WHERE NewShowDate<='2014-05-13 00:00:00'
ORDER BY NewShowDate ASC
```

or reference expressions in `WHERE` clauses.

```
SELECT E.ID
     , E.Name
     , E.StartDate
     , E.Repeats
     , A.ShowDate
     , DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) AS NewShowDate
     , (T.Day-1) AS NewDay
FROM Planner_Lessons E JOIN
 Planner_LessonTimesNew T
 ON T.LessonID = E.ID INNER JOIN Planner_Sessions S ON S.UserID=T.UserID JOIN
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ID DAY) as ShowDate
  FROM `Planner_Tally`
  ORDER BY ID ASC
 ) A 
 ON MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0 AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate AND E.Deleted='No' AND T.Deleted='No'
WHERE S.SID='1234'
  AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) <= '2014-05-13 00:00:00'
ORDER BY NewShowDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` to filter `NewShowDate`,where clause will not filter the records for your custom aliase based column or the results from aggregate function you can filter them by using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT E.ID
     , E.Name
     , E.StartDate
     , E.Repeats
     , A.ShowDate
     , DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(A.ShowDate, INTERVAL (T.Day-1) DAY), INTERVAL T.StartTime HOUR_SECOND) AS NewShowDate
     , (T.Day-1) AS NewDay
FROM Planner_Lessons E JOIN
 Planner_LessonTimesNew T
 ON T.LessonID = E.ID INNER JOIN Planner_Sessions S ON S.UserID=T.UserID JOIN
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ID DAY) as ShowDate
  FROM `Planner_Tally`
  ORDER BY ID ASC
 ) A 
 ON MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0
 AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate AND E.Deleted='No' AND T.Deleted='No'
 WHERE S.SID='1234'
 HAVING NewShowDate<='2014-05-13 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY NewShowDate ASC
```